# If $G$ and $H$ are groups, prove that $(G \times H, x)$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that, if $(G,\ast)$ and $(H,\bullet)$  are groups, then the Cartesian Product $G \times H$ with the operation
$(g_1,h_1) \circ (g_2, h_2) := (g_1 \ast g_2, h_1 \bullet h_2)$

$(G \times H, \circ)$  is a group.

My answer.
Let $(G \times H, \circ) = I$ with $(i_g, i_h)$ as element, then
$i_g \in G$ and $i_h \in H$, because G and H are groups, so, closed.

i) Closure - As $G$ is a group $i_g = (g_1 \ast g_2)$ is closed on $G$, then is closed on $I$. As $H$ is also a group $i_h = (h_1 \bullet h_2)$ is closed on $H$. Then $(i_g, i_h)$ is closed on $I (G \times H,\circ)$.

ii) Associativity - As G and H are groups, $ \forall (i_g, i_h)$ associativity holds.

iii) Identity - As $G$ and $H$ are groups, $\exists (i_{ge}, i_{he}) \in I $ where $i_{ge}$ is the identity of $G$ and $i_{he}$ is the identity of $H$.

iv) Inverse - As $G$ and $H$ are groups, $\exists (i^{-1}_g, i^{-1}_h)$ which is the inverse element of $(i_g, i_h)$.

Is that answer ok?

Comment: You're right about what the identity and inverse elements are, but you haven't really shown that they are indeed these things. Take advantage of how multiplication is defined in your (potential) group $G\times H$.

Comment: No. The question asks you to prove that it is a group, not to show that it is a group. E.g. you have shown $\forall G, H: \exists (i_{ge}, i_{he}) \in I$ but not that $\forall G, H: 1_{G x H} = (i_{ge}, i_{he}) \in I$.

Comment: If you are still stuck, look at 6.2 from http://www.fatih.edu.tr/~bkokluce/alg/notes6.pdf for an example of how to prove the properties

Comment: My original question asked to show and not prove. I didn't notice that are not the same thing.

Comment: The notes (6.2) left me with a doubt. I did not understand why it represents the inverse as $(a^1_1, a^{-1}_2)$ and not $(a^{-1}_1, a^{-1}_2)$